# Using awk to remove all lines that contain a duplicated value in a specific column based on a calculation performed on other columns

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to find a way to remove the lines (of a tab delimited table) if the value (string) in column x is repeated, including the first instance, but only if the difference between columns y and z is not the same for all replicates. I know that this command removes duplicates after the first instance: awk '!seen[$3]++' filename, but I want to include the first line where the duplicate value was found. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
x   y    z
a   10   20
b   15   25
b   15   30
b   10   20
c   15   20
d   20   30
e   10   20
e   15   25
e    5   15
f   30   40
```

Would become:

```
x   y    z
a   10   20
c   15   20
d   20   30
e   10   20
e   15   25
e    5   15
f   30   40
```

Here all lines that had "b" in column x were removed since more than one line had "b" in that column AND because the difference between values in column y and z was not always the same for these lines. Lines with "e" in column x stayed because the difference between the values in y and z was always 10.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Note: I am a beginner with awk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

double  pass algorithm, mark and sweep

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if($1 in a) {if(a[$1]!=$3-$2) d[$1]} 
               else a[$1]=$3-$2; next} 
     !($1 in d)' file{,}

a   10   20
c   15   20
d   20   30
e   10   20
e   15   25
e    5   15
e   30   40
```

**Explanation**

`NR==FNR` in the first scan of the file

`if($1 in a)` if first field is already seen

`if(a[$1]!=$3-$2)` but the delta is different from earlier

`d[$1]` add the field to the delete list

`else a[$1]=$3-$2` if the field wasn't seen before, add the field with delta

`next` proceed to the next record until all lines are done

we're now in the second scan

`!($1 in d)` print all the lines if not in the delete list compiled above

`file{,}` bash shorthand for writing `file file`

Comment: It worked, thank's a lot! (I fixed my typo, it was actually in the input table.

Comment: I have been studying your code since yesterday to try to figure out what each part does, but I am having a little bit of trouble, would you mind briefly explaining it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: when you use if($1 in a) to check if the field was already seen, you are verifying if it is present in array 'a'? Where do you define 'a' and how does awk know that it has to write $1 in 'a' at each line it reads? Thanks

Comment: Until it's defined there's nothing in it, so it works out. It's defined when you add the first element a[$1]

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1][$3-$2]; next} length(a[$1])==1' file file
x   y    z
a   10   20
c   15   20
d   20   30
e   10   20
e   15   25
e    5   15
f   30   40
```